# Navigation Components and Headless Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-architecture-navigation

Suppose, using Navigation Architecture Components, I'm within a fragment, `Fragment_A`, and want to do a small task using a Headless fragment. My questions are:

1. How to properly/correct way to add a headless fragment from within `Fragment_A`?
2. How to detect that I'm navigating out from `Fragment_A`, that started the headless fragment so that I can remove the headless fragment?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add a headless fragment by using [`getChildFragmentManager()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/fragment/app/Fragment#getChildFragmentManager()) and doing a normal `FragmentTransaction`. The benefit of using the child `FragmentManager` is that all of the child fragments are removed when the parent is removed.

Comment: Thank you very much. Please, keep doing the good work. It make things so easy. However, suppose I'm on `Fragment_A` and want to know if I've navigated from this destination, how would I get this from within the fragment itself and without using `navController.addOnDestinationChangedListener`? I mean, are there any other ways?

Comment: Actually what I'm trying to achieve is to reset `ViewModel` values.

Comment: `OnDestinationChangedListener` is there for a reason, use that.